# Why Joomla Bootstrap and official bootstrap have different css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla-template

I am using Joomla 3.2.1 and I did a [MVC component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/3.1/Introduction) and a menu to it so now in /components/com_MY_COMPONENT_NAME/views/ONE_VIEW_NAME/tmpl/default.php I can write any HTML/PHP I want.

I have been doing tests of some bootstrap examples and I realize that the CSS is not exactly the same.

Eg. Button `btn btn-primary` must has (inspecting with fire-bug in [bootstrap's website](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons)):

```
background-color: #006DCC;
background-image: linear-gradient(#08C, #04C);
```

But... trying the same (coping the whole table) on my Joomla I see that the css is:

```
background-color: #206991;
background-image: none;
```

Here the result:

[image]

You can appreciate that the `font-size` is different, but also are `line-height`, `border-radius` and `margin-bottom`

**This may sound quite trivial**, but the point is why are different. If I continue using bootstrap classes I may find some unexpected behaviours/problems.

There is no joomla template that ensures me that using bootstrap like the original?

Comment: Lodder's answer is correct. If you need the latest version of Bootstrap in Joomla today, take a look at some of the third-party templates like http://www.joostrap.com/ that implement Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thank you, yes I thought that Joomla 3 has Bootstrap 3, but no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer. As Bootstrap has been progressing, then went for a new sort of style since version 3. They've gone for a more of a flat UI style.

Joomla still has Bootstrap 2.3.2 and therefore uses the older style which isn't flat. Updating the Bootstrap files on your server will be an extremely big task as so many things we're changes, for example the grid class names. I'm not sure when Bootstrap 3 will be used but I assume it might come with Joomla 4.x

Comment: Add to this the fact that Bootstrap is made to be very customizable and has a variables.less file in the media/jui/bootstrap/less directory. That's probably from Bootstrap's distributed variables.less file, which is also different from the template's variable.less file. So there's a ton of reasons why this will never match up that way.